# Can I unload Gutenberg Block CSS even if using Block Editor?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome-devtools

I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52277629/remove-gutenberg-css) and [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-gutenberg-css/). All said that if one use classic editor, then he can unload the Gutenberg Block CSS safely.

However, currently I am using Block editor, can I still unload the Block CSS? I search a lot of articles but cannot find any, so I make a test by myself.

I load a page https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/12-solutions-when-your-outlook-is-slow/ and use Chrome DevTools to check the coverage of the block CSS, the result is below:

[image]

So actually 99.3% codes in block CSS is not used at all. And I check the 0.7% codes and they are seems to be useless. So I use Asset Cleanup Pro to unload the block CSS site wide. And then retest the same page again. And it seems the page is loaded without any outstanding changes. At least, I cannot notice any changes.

So, does that mean I can also upload the block CSS for posts that are edited with the block editor?

I am using the latest version of WordPress(**5.8**).

Comment: Note that the version of WP you are using matters here

Comment: Particularly the behaviour of v5.8 is different to that of 5.7 and below

Comment: @TomJNowell, I am using version 5.8, the latest version of WP.

Comment: I can't find any evidence that Gutenberg is responsible for this, the tag it's in has WP Rocket critical CSS markers, and the class you reference in your screenshot is being used in classic widgets not blocks